# Drupal 7: Users or content nodes. Where do I put data?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Here are few things that I want to do with my data:

1. Add data without necessarily creating a user related to it. (as a node, maybe)
2. Create users related to that data, whenever needed.
3. Enable users to edit data related to them only without affecting anything else.
4. Make data easily searchable and filterable.

So what's the best approach? Do I create MANY users and add field to them with data, or create nodes?

And yes I am a beginner in Drupal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very vague, but here is some general advice.

Only create Users if they really are USERS. Don't use the user entity to store general data, unless those data fields pertain to the user.

For example, if you need to store the mailing address of a user, add that field to the user object.